# Local Maxima (or Pour Point) Pixel Value extract in Raster

Tags: python, gdal

I am doing watershed & pourpoint using python GDAL. I have calculated

- Fill,
- Flow-Direction &
- Flow-Accumulation

using Python & GDAL.

The next is to get Pour Point in certain window Size. Please Guide me accordingly using python GDAL.